# DRF throw django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured when override get_queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework throw:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "customuser-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

when I try to ***override get_queryset*** . 
My User serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    Represent User Serializer class.
    """
    teacher_account = TeacherSerializer(required=False)
    student_account = StudentSerializer(required=False)

    account_type = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['url', 'username', "password", 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', "account_type", 'teacher_account', 'student_account']

        email_validator = UniqueValidator(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(), message="A user with that email already exists.")

        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
            "email": {"required": True, "validators": [email_validator]}
        }

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('teacher_account', 'student_account')
        return queryset
```

users/models.py:

```
class StudentAccount(models.Model):
    """
    Represent student's account model.

    """
    classes = models.ManyToManyField('classroom.Class', related_name="students")


class TeacherAccount(models.Model):
    """
    Represent teacher's account.

    use get_subject_name from {root}/utils.py for get name of the subject.
    """

    subject_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Предмет", choices=SUBJECTS_CHOICES, blank=False, default=0)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    Represent Custom user model, inherited from AbstractUser

    account_type = 0(teacher) or 1(student)
    """
    student_account = models.OneToOneField(StudentAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user")
    teacher_account = models.OneToOneField(TeacherAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user")

    account_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    first_name = models.CharField("-", max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField("-", max_length=150, blank=False)
```

My views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    # queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    # queryset_raw = CustomUser.objects.all()
    # queryset = UserSerializer.setup_eager_loading(queryset_raw)
    model = CustomUser
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        # queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
        return queryset
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers
from knox import views as knox_views

from .views import UserViewSet, ClassViewSet, LoginView, LessonViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename="CustomUser")
router.register('classes', ClassViewSet)
router.register('lessons', LessonViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='knox-login'),
    path('logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="knox_logout"),
    path('logoutall/', knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view(), name="knox_logoutall"),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

I realized, that it can be fixed if I will override url for page which show user model details.But i think there are more correct answer.

```
path('api/users/<int:pk>/', UserViewSet.as_view({"get": "retrieve", "put": "update", "delete": "destroy"}), name="customuser-detail")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), the `basename` you provide when registering a `ViewSet` to your router will be used to generate the URL patterns. You provided `basename=CustomUser`, which has capitalization.

As the error points out (also: see [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined) on how the hyperlinked views are determined and the default names are constructed) your basename should be lowercase.

If you want to keep capitalization see previous link to documentation to implement custom `view_name='CustomUser-detail'` on the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

Comment: Hi! It worked for me, thank you. The question turned out to be dumb. I did not know that Django URLs works like this.
Also, the error caused by lookup_field in my serializer. Thank you for links, I don't know why I didn't use docs)